# If statement and visible binding in knockout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to display a div depending on the count of the users for the div. If the div contains more than x number of users then display the div above the users if not then don't show. I am displaying the users through a foreach loop.

View:

```
<div class="collapse in" data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: $data.Users }">

</div>

<script type="text/html" id="list">
<!-- ko if: ShowLetter -->
        <div id="letter" data-bind=" text: Letter"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

I also tried this in my view:

```
<div id="letter" data-bind="visible:ShowLetter, text: Letter"></div>
```

But when i render the page either i get no letters or the letters would show up for a group of users that are less than x number. My results show three groups 1st group only has 1 user and shouldn't show letter - 2nd group has 2 users which shouldn't show letter either and the 3rd group has 30 users and should show letter.

Javascript:

```
 var userViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        _self.Letter = ko.observable(data.Letter);
        _self.ShowLetter = ko.computed(function () {
            return (roleViewModel.UserCount > properties.RoleUser);
        });
    };

var typeViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ContentType = ko.observable(data.ContentType);
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        _self.Rank = ko.observable(data.Rank);
        _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
        _self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);
    };
```

How can i get my view to function properly for each group looping in the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Since the property ShowLetter is a computed observable, you must invoke it, otherwise you are just passing the prototype...

eg. 
would be

or data-bind="visible:ShowLetter, text: Letter"
would be data-bind="visible:ShowLetter(), text: Letter"

That should take care of it.

Comment: When i applied this - none of the letters are appearing where it should be. So my results return three groups each group contains a number of users. Could ShowLetter() not specific to each group as it should be?

Comment: This is incorrect and will result in your template losing its live binding. You can use a primitive, observable or computed observable without any syntax change in a data-bind.

Comment: actually doesn't break the bindings...the dom element still gets notified on changes

Answer (score 0):

In your computed, you want to call roleViewModel.UserCount()  (Not sure about RoleUser) as it's an observable. Otherwise everything look fine, although some code is missing.

Comment: yes...more code == better repsonse...present your bindings and how you set everything up...make a jsfiddle that mocks your situation

Comment: @beauxjames i provided a jsfiddle to closely resemble what i am trying to get: http://jsfiddle.net/xNdJk/1/

Comment: It's not clear whether you want one secondModel per viewmodel or if it's a shared singleton, but you forgot to instantiate the secondModel:
http://jsfiddle.net/82PVc/